# Do different/older processors run c++ code differently?

Tags: c++, processor

I was coding a function that loops through a 2d array, if the current element in the array is less than the element next to it, then I would add 1 to my int counter variable. The issue is, when I run the code on my windows based machine with a AMD ryzen 7 processor, it works correctly and the counter gets to 20 (on a 5x5 array). But when I run it on my 2014 Macbook with a intel core i5 processor, on both MacOS and Windows 10 (bootcamp) the counter only gets to 19 using the same exact block of code. Here is my loop

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i=0; i < ROWS; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < COLUMNS; j++){
        if(board[i][j] < board[i][j + 1]){
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I would think this would work in any situation.

Comment: Where does the content of board come from? Is it the same in both tests?

Comment: It should. Therefore there must be undefined behavior somewhere. Unfortunately, without a [mre] that anyone can cut/paste and reproduce your observed results, nobody will be able to help you any further.

Comment: If your board has COLUMNS columns, then that j+1 will overstep its boundary, so you’re getting undefined behaviour.

Comment: Processors don't run C++ code.   They run machine code.  Regardless you need to post an [mcve]

Comment: Processors don't run C++ code at all. Are you recompiling the code in order to run it on the other computer, or are you using the same executable?

Comment: I'm guessing your `j+1` is overflowing.   Compile with -fsanitize=address and then run it again.

Answer (score 2):

Well it would be nice to have a minimal reproducible example like others said, I think I can see it from here.

using `j+1` will let the index go out of bounds causing undefined behaviour.
Try :

```cpp
for(int i=0; i < ROWS; i++){
  for(int j=0; j < COLUMNS - 1; j++){
    if(board[i][j] < board[i][j + 1]){
      counter += 1;
    }
  }
}
```

This should avoid that problem by simply stopping one sooner

Comment: You can't possibly know the answer.   Suggestions are comments, not answers.  Also, please note what his question actually is.   This is not even remotely related to his actual question.

Comment: `board[ROWS][COLUMNS]` is a solid assumption. And yes, the OP's code is reading a bogus value on the final step. C++ **is** being executed differently in those two environments in the narrow, perverse sense that the contents of trash memory are different. UB might be undefined on the C++ level, but in this particular case it's still mostly deterministic, within the limits of compiler/build/OS.